# show that the equation $a(a+6)=317b-7$ has no integer solution $(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the equation $a(a+6)=317b-7$ has no integer solution $(a,b)$
My sketch: Since $$a(a+6)=a^2+6a$$ so $$a^2+6a=317b-7$$
or $$(a+3)^2=317b+2$$
now since $317$ is a prime so left hand side might be divisible by $317$ but not rhs hence it is not possible to have integer solution $(a,b)$.

Please help whether the approach is right or wrong.

Comment: You made some useful progress, but the next step is to consider whether 2 is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) mod 317

Answer (score 1):

Wrong.  The right hand side is not divisible by $317$.  To get a contradiction from this you have to show the left hand side **must be** divisible by $317$, "might be" is not good enough.

But you have shown that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $317$.  This is only possible if $317\equiv\pm1\pmod8$, which is not true.

Comment: can it be shown that 317b+2 is not divisible by 4 or not of the form 4k+1

Comment: @nanditamukherjee No. For example, $317\cdot 3 +2 = 1053$, which is $4\cdot 263+1$.